# Roaming - being called by numbers from abroad

Tags: calls

I think this is the correct category.
I know I have roaming disabled on my phone. Does that mean that while I'm in 1 country and my friend is in a different country, he can't call me?
Does my disabled roaming mean that he can't call me or only that I can't call him? I'm confused. He told me that the voice says my number doesn't exist. Could this be because of roaming?
Thanks in advance.
Thêta.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend can call you from a different country or vice versa even when you have disabled roaming. This option **only disables the Mobile internet** when you are roaming. It does not block or disable SMS or voice calls.

> He told me that the voice says my number doesn't exist.

Ask your friend to verify the country code. There is no way for this to occur due to disabled roaming. I know that for sure as I have used mobile phones on roaming myself.

Comment: @PierrotThêta It's okay